# Javascript changes the format of my Div in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, display

I am new to JS, HTML and CSS. I was trying to build a car dealership-like website to practice what I have learned so far and I have come to this one single problem. I made a div that would simulate a user dropdown when triggered using JS method. The method I used is when the user clicked the word car brands list it would show up the hidden div. But what happens is that without JS my dropdown design is all good, but then when JS is inserted into the equation it formats it like how it looks like without any CSS in it. Here is a picture for reference. First one is how it should be, the second one is how it looks with JS in it. Please pardon my bad usage of the tools in stack overflow. I am also new here.

```js
var carListDropdown = document.getElementById("car-brand-dropdown")
carListDropdown.style.display = "none";

function carListDrop(){
    if(carListDropdown.style.display === "none"){
        carListDropdown.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        carListDropdown.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
#car-brand-dropdown {
  background: black;
  height: 350px;
  width: 500px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-right: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  transform: translateX(700px);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="car-brand-list" onclick="carListDrop()">Car Brands</div>

<div id="car-brand-dropdown">
        <ul class="car-brand-list-one">
          <li><a href="#">Aston Martin</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bentley</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Chevrolet</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dodge</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Fiat</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ford</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="car-brand-list-two">
          <li><a href="#">Honda</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Jaguar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Jeep</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">KIA</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lamborghini</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Land Rover</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lexus</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lotus</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="car-brand-list-three">
          <li><a href="#">Mazda</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Mercedes-Benz</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Mini</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Mitsubishi</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nissan</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Porsche</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Subaru</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Toyota</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Volkswagen</a></li>
        </ul>  
    </div>
```

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afxsj.png)

[How it looks with JS inserted into the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uou6J.png)

Comment: the modern and smarter solution is not to add `inline-style` through JS but to add/remove classes: `element.classList.toggle('class-name');` which also removes the need for if/else statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit this

```
var carListDropdown = document.getElementById("car-brand-dropdown")
carListDropdown.style.display = "none";

function carListDrop(){
 if(carListDropdown.style.display === "none"){
    carListDropdown.style.display = "flex";
 } else {
    carListDropdown.style.display = "none";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I removed your entire JS as it is not needed. We can do it directly with the `onclick-trigger`
2. I changed the ID of the element to a class for specificty weight reasons.
3. I added a class (.none) that contains `display: none;` to hide that element.
4. I changed the onclick-trigger to `document.querySelector('.car-brand-dropdown').classList.toggle('none');`

`document.querySelector('.car-brand-dropdown')` will select your list just like `getElementById` just the modern statement that can be used to select calsses, ID, tags...

`classList.toggle('none)` will remove the class `.none` if the elemnt has this class and add it, if the element does not have this class. So no need for `if/else`-statments.

```css
.car-brand-dropdown {
  background: black;
  height: 350px;
  width: 500px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-right: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  transform: translateX(700px);
  z-index: 1;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="car-brand-list" onclick="document.querySelector('.car-brand-dropdown').classList.toggle('none');">Car Brands</div>

<div class="car-brand-dropdown none">
        <ul class="car-brand-list-one">
          <li><a href="#">Aston Martin</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bentley</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Chevrolet</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dodge</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Fiat</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ford</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="car-brand-list-two">
          <li><a href="#">Honda</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Jaguar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Jeep</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">KIA</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lamborghini</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Land Rover</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lexus</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lotus</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="car-brand-list-three">
          <li><a href="#">Mazda</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Mercedes-Benz</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Mini</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Mitsubishi</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nissan</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Porsche</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Subaru</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Toyota</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Volkswagen</a></li>
        </ul>  
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "default" value for a Flex container uses `column` for direction whereas for your layout you really want to use `row`. The individual `ul` elements within the parent container can be left as `block` level items and the parent will have the flex properties assigned to it. With Javascript you can easily toggle the appearance of an item using `classList.toggle` ~ which saves using inline `node.style.display=...` type syntax as you can define the look far easier with CSS.

Rather than adding `inline` event handlers it is generally considered better practise to use an `external event listener` -done using `addEventListener`. This makes for cleaner HTML markup and when the event handlers are stored in an external file it means they can be referenced in other pages by including that script.

```js
/* two utility functions to shorten querySelector calls */
const q=(e,n=document)=>n.querySelector(e);
const qa=(e,n=document)=>n.querySelectorAll(e);

/* find the HTML elements of interest */
const oDiv=q('.car-brand-list');
const oSel=q('#car-brand-dropdown');

/* 
 add an event handler that toggles the class of the `select` type div, 
 modifies the class of the clicked text and resets the dataset attribute
 that displays the hyperlink text when clicked.
*/
oDiv.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  oSel.classList.toggle('flex');
  this.classList.toggle('active');
  oDiv.dataset.brand='';
});

/*
  assign a click handler to each hyperlink - the functionaliyt of the
  hyperlinks is unclear but here it is used to display the brand selected.
*/
qa('ul[class^="car-brand"] > li > a').forEach( a=>a.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  oDiv.dataset.brand=this.textContent
}));
```

```css
*{font-family:monospace;}
a{ 
  color:white!important;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.car-brand-list{
  font-size:1.5rem;
  padding:0.25rem;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-weight:bold;
  width:100px;
}
.car-brand-list.active{ 
  background:black;
  color:white;
  border-radius:0.25rem;
}
.car-brand-list:after{
  content:" - "attr(data-brand);
  color:gray;
}
[data-brand='']:after{
  content:'';
}

#car-brand-dropdown {
  background: black;
  max-height:350px;
  color: white;
  display:none;
  border-radius:1rem;
  transition:ease-in-out all 250ms;
  z-index: 1;
}
.car-brand-list,
#car-brand-dropdown{width:500px;}

.flex{
  display:flex!important;
  justify-content:space-around;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  margin:0.25rem auto;
}

ul{
  flex:1;
  margin:1rem;
  padding:1rem;
  list-style:none;
}

ul li{
  padding:0.1rem;
  font-size:90%;
}
```

```html
<div class='car-brand-list' data-brand>Car Brands</div>
<div id='car-brand-dropdown'>
    <ul class='car-brand-list-one'>
      <li><a href='#'>Aston Martin</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Audi</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Bentley</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>BMW</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Chevrolet</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Dodge</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Fiat</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Ford</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='car-brand-list-two'>
      <li><a href='#'>Honda</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Jaguar</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Jeep</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>KIA</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Lamborghini</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Land Rover</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Lexus</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Lotus</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='car-brand-list-three'>
      <li><a href='#'>Mazda</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Mercedes-Benz</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Mini</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Mitsubishi</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Nissan</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Porsche</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Subaru</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Toyota</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Volkswagen</a></li>
    </ul>  
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you'd better use `addEventListener`, but not html onclick attr.

**JS:**

```
document.querySelector('.car-brand-list').addEventListener('click',function(){
  carListDrop();
})
```

Comment: **down-voted for following reason:** Technical incorrect answer. There is no reason to not use the `onclick`-attribute. The `onclick`-attribute consumes elss computing power then an `eventListener`. Also this "answer"  does not attempt to adress the issue asked by the OP.